# WooCommerce and Android

Tags: php, android, wordpress, woocommerce

I am building an Android app for a WordPress website and have a couple of questions:

How would I pass through an order to the normal woocommerce order system, for example they add items to the basket but how does it now go to the system.

Also, how would they get an automated email confirming they order like you can set up in woocommerce?

I know there is an API which returns results in JSON but haven't seen how exactly an order would be added and so on.

Comment: for API https://github.com/kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library

Comment: Documentation http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/